# Algorithm for chain formation from set of pairs

Tags: algorithm, chain

In the development of a simulation program I have come to a set of numerical pairs as an intermediate result. The pairs are formed by unsigned (positive integers), strictly ordered (if the pair is [n1, n2] then n1 "<" n2), and they are not repeated (if [n1, n2] and [n3,  n4] are pairs in the set, then n1 != n3 or n2 != n4). There are two especial types of pairs: those whose first element is 0, open pairs; and those whose second element is the largest number in the set of components of the pairs, NMAX, close pairs (actually the number NMAX is 0, but this is just a convenient nomenclature).

From this set of pairs I construct sequences of linked pairs, chains, which start with an open pair, end with a close pair, and whose consecutive pairs share a numerical value (if  [n1, n2] and [n3,  n4] are consecutive pairs in the chain then n2 = n3). The chains are of the type [0, n1][n1, n2][n2, n3]...[nm, NMAX]. The length of the chains can vary from 2 to the number of pairs in the set.
I am looking for an algorithm that constructs all the possible chains from a given set of pairs.

The number of pairs in the set is finite and known, and depending on the simulation it can vary from few hundreds to millions. For the hundreds I can think of a procedure, but for the (very) large numbers an efficient method is required.
I have made some searches but no success, although there must be many things on this subject (f.eg. in gene sequencing from short chains of aminoacids).
Ideas and guidance appreciated!

Comment: Naive := N^2; sort-and distroy := Nlog(N); Hashing := N

Comment: Thanks! Let me follow the threads and revert with what I find. I have already written a program which seems to work well with the small set of data, but still need to test with the larger ones.

Comment: I have changed the approach: instead of working with a set of pairs and considering it a problem of chains/dominoes, I have converted the problem into one of reading all the branches of a tree (graph).

Comment: Because of `n1 < n2` you only need to search for n1. So it becomes a search problem.